# Assembly language x86 to machine code : which come first displacement or immediat data

Tags: machine-code

i wanna get the machine code for this instruction : **MOV[BX+3465H],6754H**.

the code of "MOV immediate to memory" is : *1100,011w* and w=1 cuze we are on 16 bits so the first byts is *1100,0111*.

for the 2nd its **MOD reg r/m** and mod=10, reg=000, r/m= 111.which means  *1000,0111*.

**Here is my question** : for the 3rnd and the 4th, do i have to start by 3465H which is the displacement or by 6754H the "Immediate data"?
thanks.

Comment: why dont you just assemble it and then look at the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displacement comes first, as shown in the [manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

[image: format]